# Error in Xamarin.iOS build: Given path's format is not supported

Tags: xamarin.ios

In an iOS project in Visual Studio 2015, networked to a Mac, I get this error on build...

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(411,3): error : The given path's format is not supported.

The same solution copied to the Mac builds and runs OK in Visual Studio for Mac preview.

Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets, at line 411 position 3 is this:

```
<SmartCopy
    SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)"
    Condition="'$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true'"
    SourceFiles = "@(_BundleResourceWithOutputPath)"
    DestinationFiles = "@(_BundleResourceWithOutputPath -> '%(OutputPath)')"
/>
```

Question: Ids there any way tosee what these tokens resolve to at build-time?

Note: Here is the build output that fails...

```
. . .
1> Copying file from '/Users/user123483/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TrySpeechPlus/d33d40e519762246de1faff7c177fd44/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/optimized/Images/whtball2.PNG' to '/Users/user123483/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TrySpeechPlus/d33d40e519762246de1faff7c177fd44/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/TrySpeechPlus.app/Images/whtball2.PNG'
1> SmartCopy: 2017-02-11T10:05:56.0785600-05:00 - Deserializing outputs
1> SmartCopy: 2017-02-11T10:05:56.0805590-05:00 - Creating output items
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(411,3): error : The given path's format is not supported.
1> SmartCopy: 2017-02-11T10:05:56.1110734-05:00 - Finished
1>Done executing task "SmartCopy" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "_CopyResourcesToBundle" in project "TrySpeechPlus.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Answer (score -1):

The error is caused by the space in the filename (Program Files (x86)).

A fix is to replace the space with the correct escape string

> Replace(" ","%20")